# Responsive E-commerce site? One version vs Multi-version

Tags: asp.net, mobile, responsive-design, e-commerce, zurb-foundation

Our company decide to not support IE7-8 which is super good new year news And I want to apply zurb-foundation5 css to our existing medium size e-commerce site so mobile user can have better UX/UI experience. However, I realize that many elements such as html or asp needs to be restructured and duplicated if I want to make the site display well on mobile. This would cause slow speed of site experience and perhaps even some other issues. However, If I made separate site for mobile, I would have to maintain two sites!!

My question is 
   What are the pros and cons of making a separate site for mobile vs. merging responsive css to current site and modify, rewrite, duplicate, move around html/elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pros of a responsive site:

1. A single codebase for a website can serve both mobile and desktop users.
2. Easy to maintain and change code for all users.

Cons of a responsive site:

1. The mobile version of the website loaded on smartphones has the same size and complexity as the desktop version.
2. The loading time will be much higher than the mobile counterpart.

I'd recommend you to go with adaptive design which most of the businesses are adopting these days. In an adaptive design approach, a server can choose how to optimally render pages, as well as enhance or remove functionality on the fly, based on the capabilities detected. It allows you to focus on different kinds of consumers with different device configutrations. 
Adaptive design has following advantages -

1. It allows you to capture user intent based on user specifications.
2. The code need not be written from scratch for the mobile site.
3. The performance and load time is faster than a responsive website.

You can refer to this article for further reading - http://venturebeat.com/2013/11/19/responsive-design-adaptive/

Answer (score 0):

One of the most compelling reasons for making a responsive e-commerce website is that Google recommend it!

Bear in mind Google's market share and that most of your [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) effort will be for Google. The following configuration is detailed by [Google](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/recommendations-for-building-smartphone.html), the highlight is their own:

> Sites that use responsive web design, i.e. sites that serve all
>   devices on the same set of URLs, with each URL serving the same HTML
>   to all devices and using just CSS to change how the page is rendered
>   on the device. **This is Google’s recommended configuration**.